# An adjective for some that feels "real"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that is used quite often to mean something that feels real like you can reach out and grab it. Like it has substance.

It's used most often around me to refer to user interface or game design.

Like when a UI has weight and feels like it has substance behind it you say it's ...............

I originally thought of...

- Visceral
- Corporeal
- Ephemeral (although I was looking for an antonym of this)

But none of them are correct. But it is a word with the same "al" ending I think.

Comment: *Re**al*** ends in *-al*.

Comment: Are you thinking of *substantial*?

Comment: @Jim haha! Actually, I think I just remembered it. "Tangible". I think that's my brain was looking for. I think writing this question just popped it into my head. Lol!

Comment: _Palpable_ is also possible here.

Comment: *Virtual* - it looks or feels real, but is just an appearance of something real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [tangible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible) (as per Merriam-Webster)

> easily seen or recognized
>
> able to be touched or felt

Comment: Yes! Thanks. It popped into my head about the same time as you answered. Thanks :-)